# How to handle Categorical data with an object list for a NN input?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a neural network for a game. In the game I may have many characters and those characters have some attributes. Also, my current status is independent from those characters. If I want to get current status, I would set an non rectangular array like

```
[Hp,Xp,[[Item1.name,Item1.age,Item1.multiplier]...[Item_n.name,Item_n.age,Item_n.multiplier]], [Player2.Hp,Player2.xp, Player.items[[]]...]
```

I have tried to flatten the input, but in this case, NN considers each order as different output, which raises a need for calculating each order individually. If I use a RNN to summarize an output from them to consider the action, then I lose the information about whether I sell the item or I buy an enhancing item etc. And also I need the index of the input for output.

What is the most computationally effective way to handle this input, so that NN does not need the consider an objects order but keeps its index?